# Click on the whole screen

Tags: screen, onclicklistener

I have a project where I need to set a click listener on the whole screen (when screen is clicked on I collect the values of the accelerometer).

I only see everywhere that I need to set a button (isn't it possible without a button?) which can be transparent and with the same dimension as the screen. Is there any other possibility or do the OnClickListener only works when a button is used?

I hope I've been understandable enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did:

1) In my xml view code, I checked the name of the Layout wich includes all the others "ConstraintLayout"

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

`//Other layouts`

`>`

2) And then I add this in my activity after implementing View.OnTouchListener :

`((ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main)).setOnTouchListener(this);`

`@Override`

`public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {`

```
//DO THINGS


return false;
```

`}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are in android (which it sounds like) go to the xml view code and add android:onClick="your method to be called when clicked". The go to the activity code and add in the method you assigned to the onClick attribute.

xml view code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:background="@drawable/tempback"
    android:onClick="clickListener"

    >
```

Then in the activity code:

```
public void clickListener(View v){
  if(v.getId() == R.id.idOfViewWithClickListener){ //Thismight be optional
      //What you want to happen when the view has been clicked
}
}
```